# Python beautifulsoup trying to remove html tags 'span'

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to remove

```
[<span class="street-address">
            510 E Airline Way
           </span>]
```

and I have used this clean function to remove the one that is in between `< >`

```
def clean(val):
 if type(val) is not StringType: val = str(val)
 val = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '',val) 
 val = re.sub("\s+" , " ", val)
 return val.strip()
```

and it produces `[ 510 E Airline Way ]`

i am trying to add within "clean" function to remove the char `'['` and `']'` and basically i just want to get the `"510 E Airline Way"`.

anyone has any clue what can i add to `clean` function?

thank you

Comment: where exactly are you using beautifulsoup here?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using re:

```
>>> import re
>>> s='[<span class="street-address">\n            510 E Airline Way\n           </span>]'
>>> re.sub(r'\[|\]|\s*<[^>]*>\s*', '', s)
'510 E Airline Way'
```

Using BeautifulSoup:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> s='[<span class="street-address">\n            510 E Airline Way\n           </span>]'
>>> b = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> b.find('span').getText()
u'510 E Airline Way'
```

Using lxml:

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> s='[<span class="street-address">\n            510 E Airline Way\n           </span>]'
>>> h = html.document_fromstring(s)
>>> h.cssselect('span')[0].text.strip()
'510 E Airline Way'
```