# Removing span tags in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie having trouble removing span tags after using BeautifulSoup to to grab the html from a page. Tried using "del links['span'] but it returned the same results. A few attemps at using getText() failed, as well. Clearly I'm doing something wrong that should be very easy. Help?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.python.org")
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for links in soup.find_all("span", text=re.compile(".com")):
    del links['class']
    print(links.)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Removing span _tags_ or removing span _elements_ (including their content)

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529978/python-beautifulsoup-trying-to-remove-html-tags-span

Comment: @user1929959 that question's answer is not using BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`.unwrap()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) to remove tags, preserving their contents:

```
for links in soup.find_all("span", text=re.compile(".com")):
    links.unwrap()

print soup
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending what you are trying to do, you could either use [`unwrap`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) to remove the *tag* (in fact, replacing the element by its content) or [`decompose`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) to remove the element and its content.